# Apply XSLT on an XmlDocument and get the updated XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've to make an upgrade mechanism which will update an XML documents(To another xml document).

The signature of the method that I've to respect is :

```
public XmlDocument Update(XmlDocument sourceDocument){...}
```

What would be the most efficient way to apply an XSLT file on this?

I was expecting to be able to use the [XslTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but it only accept stream and XmlWriter as parameter for the output.

So I know that I could do something like:

```
public XmlDocument Update(XmlDocument sourceDocument){
    XslTransform myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
    myXslTransform.Load("myXsl.xsl"); 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    myXslTransform.Transform(sourceDocument, null, ms);
    XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument();
    output.Load(ms);
    return output;
}
```

But I find this not very efficient(knowing that my XSLT will be to rename some nodes, add a node in-between, add a child). Is there a way to do better?

My "only" constraints are: Input/Output: XmlDocument, External XSLT to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` with the current XSLT 1.0 implementation (`XslCompiledTransform`) that Microsoft offers then you can use

```
XmlDocument resultDocument = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlWriter xw = resultDocument.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()) {
  XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
  proc.Load("myXsl.xsl");
  proc.Transform(sourceDocument, null, xw);
  xw.Close();
}
return resultDocument;
```

Comment: So `resultDocument` can be the initial `XmlDocument`? If yes, this would be great for me

Comment: No, XSLT always creates a new document but using the posted approach you avoid the step of first serializing the XSLT result to a stream to then parsing that stream as XML.

Comment: Oooooh I see, I did miss the `sourceDocument` on your code. This seems very nice and effective. Thank you very much!!
Just a small question, you mention the XSLT 1.0 implementation of microsoft, it means there is other possible implementations?

Comment: Yes, XSLT 2.0 was published in 2007, XSLT 3.0 is a work in development, there are .NET implementations of XSLT 2.0 like the .NET version of Saxon 9 (from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, http://www.saxonica.com/) and like XmlPrime (http://www.xmlprime.com).